# SPARQL Query to escape emojis?

Tags: java, sparql, virtuoso

I'm using SPARQL query to extract instances which is valid.

But using this query, I can also get instances which name contains emoticon (e.g., `http://ko.dbpedia.org/resource/`), and it gives me an error while iterating over the query resultsets. How can I escape from emojis?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {
?s ?p ?o 

FILTER regex(str(?s), "^http://ko.dbpedia.org/resource")
}

ORDER BY DESC(?s)
limit 100
```

Error message is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: Convert results are FAILED.:virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoException: Virtuoso Communications Link Failure (timeout) : malformed input around byte 34
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryExecution$VResultSet.moveForward(VirtuosoQueryExecution.java:498)
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryExecution$VResultSet.hasNext(VirtuosoQueryExecution.java:441)
    at kr.ac.kaist.dm.BBox.TypeInference.LoadTriple.processTriples(LoadTriple.java:92)
    at kr.ac.kaist.dm.BBox.TypeInference.TypeInferenceMain.main(TypeInferenceMain.java:110)
```

Sample Code is as follows.

```
VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql, set);
        ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();

        int i = 0;
        while(results.hasNext()){        //  <-----  LoadTriple.java:92 here.
```

---

I just posted the extended version of this question on [virtuoso-opensource issue #543](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/543).

---

I just want to escape from emoji rather than including all possible characters like `"FILTER regex(?s, \"[a-zA-Z가-힣~!@#$%^&*()-_=+|'<>]+\")  }"`

Answer (score 1):

`ENCODE_FOR_URI()` should work:

```
FILTER regex(ENCODE_FOR_URI(str(?s)), "^http://ko.dbpedia.org/resource")
```

...though you would also need to URI encode the regex match string:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fko.dbpedia.org%2Fresource
```

Comment: I added ENCODE_FOR_URI, but gives me the same error on the same line `results.hasNext()`

Comment: Oh, this seems like a Unicode/UTF-8 issue with either Virtuoso or Jena.  I.e. it is misinterpreting the Korean characters as emoji's.  It seems you post to the Virtuoso is the best bet for resolving the issue.